# How to 'retrieve' browser-typed 404 url and make it auto redirect on c#

Tags: c#, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a c# web application on i.e. http://mysite.com

User opens his browser and types http://mysite.com/anywrongpath

Which I want to do is to get the "exact" url ( /anywrongpath ) and THEN redirect that user to i.e. /MainPage.aspx

I think I can handle redirection with:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpException httpException = Server.GetLastError() as HttpException;
    if (httpException.ErrorCode == 404)
       Response.Redirect("/MainPage.aspx");
}
```

However, I have no idea how to handle the retrieve process of typed url. I made a research of "Sessions" , "Request.ServerVariables" , "Request.Url" etc but I couldnt solve the problem.

I am open for any idea how to solve it, and really glad if you give tiny code samples, thanx

Murat

Comment: What's wrong with `Request.Url`?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are already doing this but you may want to set up a custom 404 page. You can put your redirect there and most likely capture the URL at that point as well. This link talks about editing the web.config to do that. http://serverfault.com/questions/68137/how-to-configure-a-web-config-file-to-allow-custom-404-handling-while-still-disp

Comment: if the user comes from /mypage1 to /mypage2 by clicking something, yes I can get the previous url by `Response.Redirect("server-error.aspx?404&" & Request.Url.ToString())` But when the user makes a "first access" by manually typing to browser, I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your web.config file and put something like this in the `system.web` section

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="MainPage.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

When your user types an address like mysite.com/non-existant, IIS redirects him to `mysite.com/MainPage.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/non-existant`

This way, you can get the `Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]`